# Python - Identify a negative number in a list

Tags: python, list, count, identify

I need help doing a program which should receive ten numbers and return me the number of negative integers I typed.

Example:

If I enter:

```
1,2,-3,3,-7,5,4,-1,4,5
```

the program should return me `3`.

How can I do it?

Comment: @D.Shawley That question has been banned: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/182887

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Break your problem down. Can you identify a way to check if a number is negative?

```
if number < 0:
    ...
```

Now, we have many numbers, so we loop over them:

```
for number in numbers:
    if number < 0:
        ...
```

So what do we want to do? Count them. So we do so:

```
count = 0
for number in numbers:
    if number < 0:
        count += 1
```

More optimally, this can be done very easily using a [generator expression](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) and [the `sum()` built-in](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, -3, 3, -7, 5, 4, -1, 4, 5]
>>> sum(1 for number in numbers if number < 0)
3
```

Answer (score 31):

```
sum(n < 0 for n in nums)
```

This is the most Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: I think `any` is more clear than `sum`.

Comment: @gwg The question asks for the total number of negative integers. `any` would return `True` or `False`, which isn''t the desired answer

Comment: `numbers = [1, 2, -3, 3, -7, 5, 4, -1, 4, 5]
sum(number < 0 for number in numbers)`
The result is 3.

Comment: @BoštjanMejak Just like OP said yeah

Comment: The OP’s proposal is very beautiful! Python’s idioms are supreme beauty.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use [*filter*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) to "filter" out the negatives.

`total = len(filter(lambda x: x < 0, my_list))`

Comment: Using `lambda` and `filter()` together is slower and less readable than a generator expression.

Comment: @Lattyware Well `filter` takes a `lambda`.  I just like a functional approach :).  I agree with you 100%.  I even +1 your answer.

Comment: `filter` takes a function - creating it using `lambda` is just useful in some cases. I was just commenting to say that this is generally a worse way to do this task.

Comment: most of the people behind python hate the use of `lamda`s, however they've gained a large following. I try to avoid them whenever possible.

Comment: @jamylak Sure, just thought I would share a different way than putting up a duplicate answer.

Comment: @squiguy you are also relying on `filter` building a `list` which wastes space and also means you have to add an enclosing call to `list(...)` under python 3

Comment: @squiguy The problem with this answer now is that a large portion of people use python 3 where this doesnt work unless you add `len(list(filter(lambda x: x < 0, my_list))`